# How can i get WOEID by location?

Tags: yahoo-weather-api, woe-id

I want to write a module in php for weather that catches the city name and return  weather of today.I have searched about it and i find  that yahoo have such service but it worked with WOEID .so now i have this problem:how can i get WOEID by location?